# Bug when Nested Scrolling on Android Web View

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have implemented nested scrolling in Android WebView, but when scrolling brings the AppBar to display, the bottom of the WebView is hidden by the navigation bar.

Therefore, I have avoided it by adding a margin to the WebView when the offset of the AppBar changes, but this method is simple, and when scrolling, a white gap appears at the bottom of the WebView for a moment.

[WebView screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xISb.jpg)

Chromium scrolls nicely. Is there a clean scrolling method like Chromium where white gaps aren't visible for a moment?

[Chromium screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiL1F.jpg)

The source code is shown below.

CustomWebView.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.view.NestedScrollingChild3;
import androidx.core.view.NestedScrollingChildHelper;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

import com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout;

public class CustomWebView extends WebView implements NestedScrollingChild3 {

    private int mLastY;
    private int[] mScrollOffset = new int[2];
    private int[] mScrollConsumed = new int[2];
    private int mNestedOffsetY;
    private NestedScrollingChildHelper mChildHelper;

    private boolean mOverScrolled = false;
    private boolean mScrollable;
    private boolean mScrolling;
    private boolean mPageLoading;
    private boolean mSwipeRefreshEnabled;

    private AppBarLayout mAppBarLayout;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

    private WebViewClient mWebViewClient;
    private WebChromeClient mWebChromeClient;

    public CustomWebView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.webViewStyle);
    }

    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mChildHelper = new NestedScrollingChildHelper(this);
        setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
        mOverScrolled = true;
        super.onOverScrolled(scrollX, scrollY, clampedX, clampedY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);
        final int action = event.getActionMasked();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            mNestedOffsetY = 0;
        }
        int eventY = (int) event.getY();
        event.offsetLocation(0, mNestedOffsetY);
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (event.getPointerCount() != 1|!mOverScrolled|mPageLoading) {
                    mLastY = eventY;
                    setSwipeRefreshEnabled(false);
                    break;
                } else if (!mScrollable && mScrolling && !canZoomIn()) {
                    setSwipeRefreshEnabled(false);
                    break;
                } else if (getScrollY() == 0 && mAppBarLayout.getBottom() == mAppBarLayout.getHeight() && mScrolling) {
                    setSwipeRefreshEnabled(true);
                    break;
                } else {
                    int deltaY = mLastY - eventY;

                    if (mScrolling) {
                        mScrolling = false;
                        // start NestedScroll
                        startNestedScroll(ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL);
                    }

                    // NestedPreScroll
                    if (dispatchNestedPreScroll(0, deltaY, mScrollConsumed, mScrollOffset)) {
                        deltaY -= mScrollConsumed[1];
                        mLastY = eventY - mScrollOffset[1];
                        event.offsetLocation(0, -mScrollOffset[1]);
                        mNestedOffsetY = mScrollOffset[1];
                        setSwipeRefreshEnabled(false);
                    }

                    // NestedScroll
                    if (dispatchNestedScroll(0, mScrollOffset[1], 0, deltaY, mScrollOffset)) {
                        event.offsetLocation(0, mScrollOffset[1]);
                        mNestedOffsetY = mScrollOffset[1];
                        mLastY -= deltaY;
                        setSwipeRefreshEnabled(false);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mLastY = eventY;
                mScrolling = true;
                mOverScrolled = false;
                setSwipeRefreshEnabled(false);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                // end NestedScroll
                stopNestedScroll();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    // Nested Scroll implements
    @Override
    public void setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        mChildHelper.setNestedScrollingEnabled(enabled);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNestedScrollingEnabled() {
        return mChildHelper.isNestedScrollingEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean startNestedScroll(int axes) {
        return mChildHelper.startNestedScroll(axes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean startNestedScroll(int axes, int type) {
        return mChildHelper.startNestedScroll(axes, type);
    }

    @Override
    public void stopNestedScroll() {
        mChildHelper.stopNestedScroll();
    }

    @Override
    public void stopNestedScroll(int type) {
        mChildHelper.stopNestedScroll(type);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNestedScrollingParent() {
        return mChildHelper.hasNestedScrollingParent();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNestedScrollingParent(int type) {
        return mChildHelper.hasNestedScrollingParent(type);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedScroll(int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed,
                                        int[] offsetInWindow) {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed,
                offsetInWindow);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedScroll(int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed,
                                        @Nullable int[] offsetInWindow, int type) {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed,
                offsetInWindow, type);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatchNestedScroll(int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed,
                                     @Nullable int[] offsetInWindow, int type, @NonNull int[] consumed) {
        mChildHelper.dispatchNestedScroll(dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed,
                offsetInWindow, type, consumed);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedPreScroll(int dx, int dy, int[] consumed, int[] offsetInWindow) {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, consumed, offsetInWindow);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedPreScroll(int dx, int dy, @Nullable int[] consumed,
                                           @Nullable int[] offsetInWindow, int type) {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx, dy, consumed, offsetInWindow, type);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedFling(float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedFling(velocityX, velocityY, consumed);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchNestedPreFling(float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return mChildHelper.dispatchNestedPreFling(velocityX, velocityY);
    }

    @Override
    protected int computeVerticalScrollRange() {
        final int verticalScrollRange = super.computeVerticalScrollRange();
        mScrollable = verticalScrollRange > getHeight();
        return verticalScrollRange;
    }

    @Override
    public void setWebViewClient(WebViewClient client) {
        super.setWebViewClient(client);
        mWebViewClient = client;
    }

    @Override
    public void setWebChromeClient(WebChromeClient client) {
        super.setWebChromeClient(client);
        mWebChromeClient = client;
    }

    public boolean overScrolled() {
        return mOverScrolled;
    }

    public void setAppBarLayout(@NonNull AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
        mAppBarLayout = appBarLayout;
    }

    public void setMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
        marginParams.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
        setLayoutParams(marginParams);
    }

    public void setPageLoading(boolean pageloading) {
        mPageLoading = pageloading;
    }

    public void setSwipeRefreshLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout layout) {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = layout;
    }

    public boolean isSwipeRefreshEnabled() {
        return mSwipeRefreshEnabled;
    }

    private void setSwipeRefreshEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        if (!mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
            mSwipeRefreshEnabled = enabled;
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

Tab.java

```
public class Tab extends Fragment {
...

mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener((layout, i) -> {
            if (currentFragmentTag.contains(FRAGMENT_TAG_PREFIX_WEB)) {
                Tab tab = (Tab) fm.findFragmentByTag(currentFragmentTag);
                if (tab != null) {
                    tab.getWebView().setMargins(0, 0, 0, layout.getBottom());
                    if (layout.getBottom() == 0) {
                        layout.setElevation(0f);
                    } else {
                        layout.setElevation(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.toolbar_elevation));
                    }
                }
            }
        });

...
```

Comment: Please add your code here